# How do I replace eregi function with preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

I have some coding that was done years ago for me using eregi. I know that I need to change it to preg_match but have no idea how to do this.

the code is:

```
       if (eregi("\.jpg|\.gif|\.png", $f))
          array_push($files, $path.$f);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `preg_match` here with the `i` case insensitive flag:

```
if (preg_match("/\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/i", $f)) {
    array_push($files, $path.$f);
}
```

Note that the `eregi` function was deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and removed in 7.0.0, see the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php).  It is time to upgrade to a current version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a regex to check the extension of a file. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php with `in_array` would be a better approach.

```
$path = pathinfo($f);
if(in_array(strtolower($path['extension']), array('jpg', 'gif', 'png')) {
     $files[] =  $path . $f;
}
```